# JavaFx list of average resourcebundle

Tags: java, javafx, internationalization, resourcebundle

I'm busy with some internationalization code with JavaFx 2.2 and SceneBuilder.

Currently the user can choose his language with a radioMenuItem. What I'm trying to do is to put only the available languages in this menu. The goal of this is that I haven't to modify the code when I want to add a language file.

Is there any property/method to have a list of all the RessourceBundles in a family?

Comment: well what I feel is we can do it by some logic implementations. I mean would the available languages been saved somewhere can we read it from some property file?

Comment: Yes, maybe if I look in the property folder/package and I parse the file names (like Lang_en_US.properties or Lang_fr_BE.properties). I was looking for some elegant solution with the ResourceBundle.

Comment: It's a way, but I thought there was an build in method to do it. I'll try some similar function with the language and the country.